# Save Word document (.docx) using Office.js API to back-end server

Tags: javascript, java, spring, ms-office, openxml

I'm having some troubles saving a `byte` array (fetched from a Microsoft Office's task pane using Office.js) to a Word document file (on the server side). This is what I'm doing:

- I'm getting the content of the Word document using this [library](https://github.com/ishwormali/OffQuery)

**JavaScript**

```
$('#push').click(function () {
  $.when(OffQuery.getContent({ sliceSize: 1000000 }, function (j, data, result, file, opt) {
    // ...nothing interesting here
  })).then(function (finalByteArray, file, opt) {
    // (1) this line is changed...see the answer
    var fileContent = Base64.encode(finalByteArray); //encode the byte array into base64 string.

    $.ajax({
      url: '/webcontext/api/v1/documents',
      // (2) missing setting (see the answer)
      data: fileContent,
      type: 'POST'
    }).then(function () {
      // updateStatus('Done sending contents into server...');
    });
  }).progress(function(j, chunkOfData, result, file, opt){
    // ...nothing interesting here
});
```

- Then in a Spring controller I'm doing this:

**Java / Spring**

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) // As OOXML
public void create(@RequestBody String fileContent, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception { // TODO
  LOGGER.debug("{} {}", request.getMethod(), request.getRequestURI());
  //LOGGER.debug("fileContent: {}", fileContent);
  try {
    val base64 = Base64.decodeBase64(fileContent); // From Apache Commons Codecs

    FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("assets/tests/output/some_file.docx"), base64);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Crash! Something went wrong here while trying to save that...this is why: ", e);
  }
}
```

...but the file is getting saved as-is; basically is saving the `byte` array into the file as a text document.

Am I missing something? Do you have any clues? Somebody that has worked with Office.js, Task Panes and things like that?

Thanks in advance...

**UPDATE 1**

Turns out that the `finalByteArray` is getting converted into a Base64 string (`fileContent`), but when I try to do the reverse operation in Java is not working...if somebody has done that before, please let me know. I have tried:

1. The sample in this [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) page
2. [Unibabel](https://github.com/coolaj86/unibabel-js)
3. [base64-js](https://github.com/beatgammit/base64-js/blob/master/lib/b64.js)

...on the Java side (to decode the Base64 `String` into a `byte` array):

1. The default [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) encoder/decoder
2. The [Base64 Apache codec](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html)

Comment: what is base64 variable real data type?

Comment: @stiv it is of type `byte[]`

Comment: If it were me, I'd change "val" to "byte[ ]" just to see what happens. Next I'd send a simple docx file (without using Office.js) then compare the copy with the original.  If that works then the problem is with the Office.js generated file.And here are some MS examples of using Office.js to send a docx file: [Get the whole document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj715279.aspx) "Create a task pane app for Word that gets a reference to all of the content of the current document and sends it to a web server."

Comment: why do you cut off the last character from fileContent when you decode it?

Comment: plz log base64 length and output file lenght and report them here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I found the error. It was on the client side. There is a function included in the **Office.js SDK** that does the conversion between the `byte` array into a Base64 `string` ― although I'm not sure if it's shipped with all versions, I'm using **Office.js SDK 1.1**.

So I changed the conversion to:

```
var fileContent = OSF.OUtil.encodeBase64(finalByteArray);
```

...and in the AJAX call I added the `contentType` setting:

```
  $.ajax({
    //...
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    // ...
    type: 'POST'
  }).finish(function () {
    // ...
  });
```

By setting the content type correctly I was able to post "the right content" to the server.

> Even if I do the correct Base64 conversion without setting the correct
>   `Content Type`, the received data in the Spring controller is
>   different (larger in this case) than the one reported in the client
>   side.

I hope this may help someone else in the future. The examples in the Microsoft Web are quite clear, but for some reason "there is always something different between environments".

Answer (score 1):

There is no obvious error in your code, except (as commented) that I don't know why you cut off the last character from your code.

Why don't you use a javascript debugger like Firebug and a remote Java debugger for your Webserver to check every step in your processing and control the content of the various variables (Javascript fileContent, Java fileContent, Java base64) to find out where the error creeps in.

Comment: They are the same: in the JavaScript code, the base64 conversion matches with what I'm receiving in the Java code; even the `byte` array content; but for some reason, whenever I save those bytes in the file, it's getting saved as-is (see update 1 on the original question)

Comment: so just FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("assets/tests/output/some_file.docx"), base64); is failing?

Comment: It's not that "it's failing" but that it is not creating the correct content that I want...and whenever I try to open the (already created) `.docx` document Word says "it's corrupted"

Comment: That is a new info. Why don't just go back to basics, take an existing word file, read it into a byte[] area, encode it, decode it, and write it out again, just to be sure that the basics work, not involving any web scenario.

And by the way, why do you cut off the last character from the fileContent variable?

Comment: I already did that, I know that works since I'm reading a file from the filesystem and copying to somewhere else by write back those bytes. I cut off the last character because the Base64 decoder that's shipped with Java 1.8 was complaining about that

Comment: finally you spotted the error yourself, great! good luck for your project